# Setup build system for ASP.NET MVC application without visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, msbuild, build-system

How to setup build system without visual stduio for .NET MVC web application?

Actually i have installed the following items on build server,

> 1. Latest .NET framework
> 2. Microsoft Visual Studio shell (isolated)
> 3. MSBuild tools
> 4. Visual Studio C++ build tools & Web Deployment build tools
> 5. Latest WiX Toolset

while running build getting the following errors,

**Errors**:

> 1. error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> 2. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>      reference?)
> 3. error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> 4. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ApiController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 5. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionFilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>      reference?)
> 6. error CS0641: Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute
> 7. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpActionExecutedContext' could not be found (are you missing a
>      using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 8. rror CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Did i miss anything to be installed on the Build System prior to start build?

Guide me to over come these errors.

**Update:**

**I resolved the above errors by installing MVC4 framework**. But i am still having other below issue for VP8 & WebM projects.

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: can you share your build script file?

Comment: "Latest .NET Framework" - possibly you need the [Developer Pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472).  Also, are you missing a package restore step?

Comment: updated my question. resolved some errors by installing MVC4 framework but having build error problem for VP8 & WebM projects